# Time since midnight program error

Tags: python

```
hour = input("Enter the hour: ")
minute = input("Enter the minute: ")
second = input("Enter the second: ")
time = str("hour:minute:second")
#
def time_since_midnight(time):
    s = time.split(":")
    seconds = int(s[0]) * 60 * 60 + int(s[1]) * 60 + int(s[2])
    return seconds;
#
print(time_since_midnight(time))
```

it doesn't work...I want to calculate the time since midnight
in seconds

edit) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hour'

I received this error message and i can't find which part is wrong

Comment: Please see the documentation on building a [mcve]. A question should include a *specific error* (not just "it doesn't work"), and the *shortest possible code* that generates that error.

Comment: `time = '{0}:{1}:{2}'.format(hour, minute, second)`

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000, Code Review takes *working* code, as described very specifically in [their on-topic page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This doesn't qualify.

Comment: @user9378599  You should dig about the issue first. Then post specific error with description.

Comment: *It doesn't work* is not a useful problem description, and *What's wrong here?* is not an actual question. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and edit both your post title and body to provide a clear problem description and ask a **specific question** related to the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time = "%s:%s:%d" % (hour, minute, second)`

But I agree with others that you should be more precise with your question, showing a minimal example of what it is that's not working, what the expected and actual outcomes are.

Try debugging simple code like this by writing unit tests or even just simply printing the value of individual variables to double check your assumptions of what certain lines are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your time construct is a constant string. Right now the value of your time variable will always be "hour:minute:second" no matter what values you enter. If you insert the following code into your script before you define your function, you will see what the issue is:

```
hour = input("Enter the hour: ")
minute = input("Enter the minute: ")
second = input("Enter the second: ")
time = str("hour:minute:second")
print time
```

You need to change it to:

time = str(hour) + ":" + str(minute) + ":" + str(second)

Comment: tsk tsk re: answering a question before it's been brought up to site standards. Note "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and its explicit reference to a question being on-topic ["as defined in the help center"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); part of that definition is including an explicit error message when asking why code fails.

Comment: Thanks for the tip =). In this case I thought it was pretty obvious what the issue was since the OP included his code, but I've definitely wasted my time answering poorly defined questions in the past!

Comment: Whether you understood the problem or not isn't the issue. Low quality questions provide no value to the site and shouldn't be answered until they're improved. Answering them before then removes all incentive for the poster to do so, as they've already gotten an answer.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I didn't actually realise there were rules regarding when a question should and shouldn't be answered, so thanks to Charles for letting me know and linking me to the relevant articles. Personally, I think that if information provided in the question is sufficient for anyone to figure out the problem, then all good, but I do see where you're coming from in trying to keep the site nice and tidy and the benefits of doing so.